# Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Cannot assign requested address [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Tags: laravel, redis

Recently, one of our servers started reporting this error intermittently:

```
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException:
Cannot assign requested address [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

In:

```
vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155
Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::onConnectionError
```

Triggered by: `artisan queue:work redis --once`

Ours is a standard Laravel 5.7 installation on an Ubuntu vm provisioned with Forge. There has been no change to any settings but this error suddenly appeared. Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Running `netstat -vatnl | grep 6379` results in this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:58244         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52098         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51171         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:33028         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49731         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41169         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60007         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51065         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52277         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47116         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56150         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36441         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:35296         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47272         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36221         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:41169         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49921         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:60007         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45921         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0     14 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:53708         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:42849         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:36441         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:38599         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:53578         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:56150         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38599         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48411         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:36221         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42849         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48276         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53578         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35296         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58244         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53708         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33028         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46072         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT
```

I'm not familiar with what's going on here so any help in understanding is much appreciated.

Comment: Any changes in your server? Maybe redis port was changed?

Comment: @Tarasovych no change that i'm aware of. Please see additional info in the question